# bash: assign variable on the fly according to the pattern in file name

Tags: bash

My bash script operates with different files located within the same directory and then execute some program for them. Each files match the following pattern where the ${receptor} keyword is always located after the second "_" of the file name. This keyword defines the group of the file.

something_something_${receptor}_repX.pdb

According to the ${receptor}, all files are devided in three groups. So I create a special function which set the name of the prefix and execute all operations in flow only for the files contained this index:

```
set_receptor () {
#receptor='5r82dim'
#receptor='2zu2dim'
receptor='7dr8dim'
}


set_receptor

for pdb in "${docking_pdb}"/*_${receptor}_*.${lig_ext}; do
pdb_name=$(basename "$pdb" .${lig_ext})
pdb_name="${pdb_name/_rep1}"
echo "Converting ${output}: the system ${pdb_name}
done
```

This means that each time when I need to switch between different groups I need to uncomment $receptor manually in the set_receptor function. How could I determine $receptor automatically in the workflow in order that my script could be executed only 1 time for any number of groups and determine each group automatically in the begining of FOR loop execution?

Comment: Please specify "usually located".

Comment: it means that the searching keyword is always after the second _ e.g. of the file money_fornothing_2zu2dim_rep4.pdb where the receptor is 2zu2dim etc

Comment: I modified my first message to precise the issue

Comment: `read -rp 'Enter receptor value ' input; case $input in ...) ...;; ...) ... ;; esac`

Comment: Why don't you pass `receptor` as a parameter of your script, or make it an environment variable.  In the latter case, you call the script by `receptor=7dr8dim bash YOURSCRIPT.sh`

Comment: Hey actually I have already thought about it but I need really to know if it would be possible to determine $receptor automatically since this keyword located always in the same place of file name :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keyword is always after the second underscore, you can use parameter expansion to extract it:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for pdb in "$docking_pdb"/*_*_*."$lig_ext" ; do
    receptor=${pdb##*/}       # Remove the path.
    receptor=${receptor#*_}   # Up to the first underscore.
    receptor=${receptor#*_}   # Up to the second underscore.
    receptor=${receptor%%_*}  # Remove everything after the 1st underscore.
    ...

done
```

Comment: I've jsut checked: it seems that it could identify automatically $ receptor ! just one question: how would be possible to add another for loop at the end of the script to loop the output produced by the first loop, according to each receptor (in order to make a summary for each file) ?

Comment: To ask a new question, ask a new question ;-)